# Why is it not saved inside the double pointer?

Tags: c

i have the next code and I have problem with those two lines of code,
`printf("Ingrese una palabra: ");` `scanf("%s",(vector+1));` 
If they were not, it works fine, but if I want to modify the word "perro" and ask one the user gives error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,a;
    char **vector;

    vector = (char**)malloc(2*sizeof(char*));

    *(vector) = "hola";
    *(vector + 1) = "perro";

    //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    printf("Ingrese una palabra: ");
    scanf("%s",(vector+1));
    //

    puts("\nImprimiendo caracter a caracter:");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++) 
    {
        for(j=0; j<strlen(*(vector+i)) ; j++)
        {
            printf("%c",*(*(vector+i)+j));
        }
        puts("");
    }

    puts("\nImprimiendo completo:");
    printf("%s\n",*vector);
    printf("%s",*(vector+1));

    free(vector);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: May you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: Isn't `(vector+1)` a pointer to a pointer? Wouldn't you want to pass a pointer to scanf? (Maybe `*(vector+1)`? Secondly those strings are read only so attempting to modify them should segfault

Comment: At `scanf("%s",(vector+1));` you are writing to read-only memory. (Subject to @MichaelPetch remark). Because you initialised the pointer with a pointer to a *string literal*. Even if you could, the input is limited to the 5 character length of the doggish *perro*.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes, but scanf receives a memory address, and when I pass it (vector * 1) I am giving it the memory address it is pointing to (vector + 1), which is the vector that is inside or is it wrong?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I'm just proving things about double pointers

Comment: With g++ and strong warning flags, I get this: `..\main.c:17:5: error: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char **' [-Werror=format=]`

Comment: @EmiliOrtega You need to learn before handling double pointers, that string literals are read only and what you apparently attempt is going to be **undefined behavior**.

Comment: On a completely unrelated not, if you are in fact using _C_ (and not C++) then this question/answer may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 1):

Stuff like `*(vector + 1)` is unnecessarily hard to read. You can just write `vector[1]`. Maybe you're doing it as an exercise, but I'm not, so I'm going to translate everything into array syntax.

You have two problems. First is this:

```
scanf("%s",(vector+1));
```

This produces a compiler warning:

```
test.c:17:16: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char **' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%s",(vector+1));
           ~~  ^~~~~~~~~~
```

(If you didn't get a compiler warning, turn them on with `-Wall` and fix all of them).

`scanf` wants a `char *`, a string. But you've given it `vector`, a list of strings, and shifted over one pointer.

`scanf` is going to try to shove a string in there anyway. `vector` has only been allocated `2 * sizeof(char*)` which is 8 bytes on a 64 bit machine. You shifted it over 1 `char *`, or 4 bytes so there's only 4 bytes left. So it can "safely" cram 3 characters in there, plus a null byte. But C is sloppy, so `scanf` can probably shove more in there without the operating system stopping it.

```
$ ./test
Ingrese una palabra: 123

Imprimiendo caracter a caracter:
hola
Segmentation fault: 11
```

It segfaults when you try to use `vector[1]` as a string, because what should be a `char *` pointing at `perro` has been overwritten with the characters `123` and a null byte. It tries to use that as a pointer to memory and blows up.

Instead, you need to pass in a `char *`. That's `*(vector+1)` or simply `vector[1]`.

```
scanf("%s", vector[1]);
```

This brings us to our next problem: you only ever allocated memory for `vector`, a list of strings. You never allocated memory for the strings themselves! Assigning constants to the list isn't a substitute. As soon as I run the corrected code, I get a Bus error.

```
$ ./test
Ingrese una palabra: adlskfj
Bus error: 10
```

This is because `vector[1]` contains a constant string `perro`. You also got a warning about this.

```
test.c:13:19: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char [6]' discards qualifiers
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    *(vector + 1) = "perro";
                  ^ ~~~~~~~
```

What that means is "hey, this is a constant string, but you're using it as if it wasn't constant!"

`scanf` tries to overwrite it and fails. It can't overwrite that "memory" because it actually points to part of the compiled binary. If you print out the pointer you'll see it's very different front he rest.

```
printf("%p\n", vector[1]);
printf("%p\n", vector);

$ ./test
0x109ce7f51
0x7ff664c08d90
```

When I look at the binary with a hex editor, I find `perro` at position `00000f51` along with other string constants in the program (yours will be at a different location).

```
00000f40: ffff 6841 0000 00e9 b4ff ffff 686f 6c61  ..hA........hola
00000f50: 0070 6572 726f 0025 700a 0049 6e67 7265  .perro.%p..Ingre
00000f60: 7365 2075 6e61 2070 616c 6162 7261 3a20  se una palabra:
00000f70: 0025 7300 0a49 6d70 7269 6d69 656e 646f  .%s..Imprimiendo
00000f80: 2063 6172 6163 7465 7220 6120 6361 7261   caracter a cara
00000f90: 6374 6572 3a00 2563 0000 0a49 6d70 7269  cter:.%c...Impri
00000fa0: 6d69 656e 646f 2063 6f6d 706c 6574 6f3a  miendo completo:
00000fb0: 0025 730a 0000 0000 0100 0000 1c00 0000  .%s.............
```

You can see the `0xf51` in `0x109ce7f51`. It's some magic memory location telling C to read from the binary, plus the offset `0xf51`. Whereas `0x7ff664c08d90` is pointing to read/write memory on the heap.

To store an array of strings, you have to allocate memory for the list ***and for the strings***.

```
vector = malloc(2*sizeof(char*));
for( i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {
    vector[i] = malloc( 256 * sizeof(char*) );
}

printf("Ingrese una palabra: ");
scanf("%s",vector[1]);
```

Note that `vector[1] = "perro"` would replace the pointer to the allocated memory with the constant string and you'd be back to the Bus error.

Also note that [I don't cast `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc#605858).

Answer (score -1):

You are accessing 2 pointeurs without having initialized them.
you need to reserve some space for you 2 vectors because they will contains characters.

Comment: He created an array of char * pointers (room for 2 `char *` pointers ) and then initialized the first 2 elements of the array to the address of two strings. So the array has appropriate space for 2 `char *` allocated for it (with malloc) and both array items are  initialized. Unfortunately they are initialized to pointers that will be in read only memory, and he forgot to do the pointer dereferencing on the `scanf`

Comment: yes the pointers are assigned to litteral strings, so has you say they are not modifiable. That's what I mean by not initialized.. I should add properly..